# Resizing accessoryInputView?

Tags: ios, resize, inputaccessoryview

I have tried and failed to resize a `UITextField` that resides inside an `UIView`, that is set as the `inputAccessoryView` of that text field.

Now I have been trying to get the resizing to work. When the user enters text of 2 lines or more, the textfield should resize, and so should the surrounding view (`inputAccessoryView`).

I have the following code in my `UITextFieldDelegate`:

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    println("textViewDidChange called")
    sendButton.enabled = textView.hasText()
    var oldHeight = textView.frame.height
    var textWidth = textView.frame.width
    textView.sizeToFit()

    var textFrame = textView.frame
    textFrame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height
    textFrame.size.width = textWidth
    textView.frame = textFrame
    var newHeight = textView.frame.height

    moveToolbarUp(newHeight - oldHeight)
    self.frame.size.height += newHeight - oldHeight
    self.superview?.updateConstraints()
}
```

Now when I type too much in the textfield, [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s866jyxxot1kvky/2015-03-09%2011.22.40.png?dl=0) happens. How can I make sure this does not happen? Also, the complete `inputAccessoryView` resets when I press the return key. Should I be using another method in the `delegate`? Should I not be calculating these heights myself? Why doesn't my `inputAccessoryView` resize properly, but only my textView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was using Autolayout, I should have used that... It works by setting a height constraint on the `UITextField`, which I then change with these calculations...